# Restricting generic type fails in a particular situation

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I like to separate my definitions from my implementations. I have an interface Entity:

```
public interface Entity<E> where E : Entity<E>
{
    EntityId EntityId { get; }

    bool ReadOnly { get; }
    
    void FailIfReadOnly();
    
    E Copy();
}
```

E is the actual entity type, such as Customer:

```
public interface Customer : Entity<Customer>
{
}
```

The problem I have is the implementation of FailIfReadOnly(): if ReadOnly == true, then throw an EntityIsReadOnlyException.

```
public class EntityIsReadOnlyException<E> where E : Entity<E>
{
    public EntityIsReadOnlyException(E entity)
        : base(string.Format("Entity {0} is read only", entity.EntityId))
    {
    }
}

public class EntityImpl<E> : Entity<E> where E : Entity<E>
{
    public EntityImpl(E other)
    {
    }

    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
    
    public void FailIfReadOnly()
    {
        if (! ReadOnly) throw new EntityIsReadOnlyException<E>(this);
    }
}
```

The `throw new EntityIsReadOnlyException<E>(this);` causes a compilation error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'EntityIsReadOnlyException.EntityIsReadOnlyException(E)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'EntityImpl' to 'E'

I can do:

```
EntityIsReadOnlyExcetion<Customer> exc = new EntityIsReadOnlyException<Customer>(customerImpl);
```

and even:

```
Entity<E> entity = new EntityImpl<E>(this);
```

but not:

```
EntityIsReadOnlyException<E> exc = new EntityIsReadOnlyException<E>(this);
```

In both cases, E is restricted to subclasses of Entity. My question is, why do I get this compilation error? It's probably something very simple.

Comment: What is the purpose of ` where E : Entity<E>` on the interface?

Comment: This is a recursive definition isn't it?
IE the type restriction is an Entity<Entity<E>> ?
Is that even possible?

Comment: @marcgravell - typically the purpose of such recursive type restrictions is to implement a clone or copy in the base class that can return the derived type.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your exception class doesn't derive from Exception:

```
public class EntityIsReadOnlyException<E> : Exception where E : Entity<E>
```

Then notice that your exception's constructor doesn't take an `Entity<E>` as a parameter, but an E.

Method 1: Change your constructor to take an `Entity<E>`:

```
public EntityIsReadOnlyException(Entity<E> entity)
```

Method 2: Pass `other` to your exception:

```
E other;
public EntityImpl(E other)
{
    this.other = other;
}

...

if (ReadOnly) throw new EntityIsReadOnlyException<E>(other);
```

Non working method: Try to cast this to an E:

```
if (ReadOnly) throw new EntityIsReadOnlyException<E>((E)(Entity<E>)other);
```

This compiles, but fails at runtime because your implementation object isn't the same type as the parameter E and cannot be cast to it.

Another minor point: your `if (!ReadOnly)` check is the wrong way around. It should be `if (ReadOnly)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

Error message is pretty clear: you can't convert EntityImpl to E... Just because Entity not derived from E nor implemented casting operators...

You can use Mark's way or rewrite Entity interface as abstract class with implicit operator E(Entity entity) and constructor with at least one parameter E instance. So all you derived classes will be able to to this.